# Converting a String to a Short

Tags: c#, string, parsing, casting

Current code:

```
short s;

s = short.Parse(this.txtFields3.Text);
```

I've gone through with debugging, and can confirm that the txtField3.Text returns an actual value from the form.

Also tried:

```
s = short.Parse(this.txtFields3.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and,

```
s = Convert.toInt16(this.textFields3.Text);
```

EDIT: The value of the variable I'm trying to put into 's' here is "EMS".

Comment: What error do you get and what value has `txtField3` on debugging?

Comment: what text does your text field contain?

Comment: What's the error? Also is your app so memory sensitive that using 2 bytes as opposed to 4 is a huge overhead that you need to use shorts instead of ints?

Comment: "EMS" is the value of the textField3.Text, the error is a "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Jesus, I have to convert the value to a short, as I'm writing the value back to a Access Database Table that contains a field that is of 'short' type.

Comment: The functions you tried calling convert a number in string form into the binary equivalent (e.g., converting "19" into 0x13).  Obviously "EMS" is not the string form of a number.  What bit pattern do you expect in the short after converting "EMS"?

Comment: Have your string numeric value inside, if not how do you convert string to numeric value.

Comment: @James is it possible your Access field is type TEXT or CHARACTER and not short?  TEXT and CHARACTER fields are [two bytes per character wide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208866(office.12).aspx).  The short data type is also sixteen bits wide and some languages/platforms use "pointer to unsigned short" or "pointer to short" as the type for pointers to wide character strings.  However I would expect C# data access methods to treat a TEXT or CHARACTER field as a string not short (although I haven't used Access very much).  How are you connecting to your Access DB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"EMS" is not a short, so the code will always fail.

Are you sure you understand what you are trying to do? Give us what you really need to do, not what you think you want to do and you will surely be helped.

**Update**

A short is a data type that represents a number. This is why "EMS" is not a short.

Comment: Well, I thought I knew was I was doing but I guess I didn't truly understand the value of a short in this case. I'm trying to convert the string value of txtFields3.Text to a short, because I'm writing it back to an Access Database table, in which, one of the fields is of a 'short' value type.

Answer (score 8):

and the value is something that fits into a short?

How about:

```
short s;
if (!short.TryParse(this.txtFields3.Text, out s)){
    s = 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I guess it isn't something that can fit into a short then? Thank you for the tip.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. But it helps me to sort out my problem. Thanks